# WCF Services on the same machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, wcf-data-services

I have 6 WCF web services in my web application.

On visiting any page on my MVC3 site I may call up to 4 or so of these WCF services.

In my live environment (as in all my environments) I have all my web services hosted on the same machine (each front end server has these services).

My issue is that the site I'm working on runs very slowly and as part of the performance improvements to the site I wanted to reduce the overhead of all these http requests to these various WCF services.

My question is, is it possible to call these web services in a 'non-http-overheady' way since they are living on the same machine anyway?

Comment: I guess it's not possible then.

Comment: you can try to serve web services on another site and application pool for performance problem.

Comment: All 6 web services are in a separate site on the same machine.

Comment: Why do you think the services are part of the problem? Have you done any performance profiling?

Comment: Yes we have using Redgate Profiler and they are taking a long time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Thumb rules in choosing endpoint' binding of WCF**

- If you require your service to be consumed by clients compatible with
  SOAP 1.1, use basicHttpBinding for interoperability
- If you require your service to be consumed within the corporate
  network, use netTCPBinding for performance
- If you require your service to be consumed over the internet and the 
  client is a WCF compatible, use wsHttpBinding to reap full benefits
  of WS* specifications
- **If you require your service to be accessible only in the same machine, use netNamedPipeBinding**
- If you require your service to be queue messages, use netMsmqBinding
- If you require your service to act as server as well as client in a
  peer to peer environment, utilise netPeerTcpBinding setting